# Как сравнить переменную с данными из массива ? python

Tags: python

У меня есть переменная, значение которой равно "False" типа string и мне хотелось бы сравнить эту переменную в операторе if с массивом возможных логических выражений ("F", "f" ,"FALSE" ,"false" ,"False" ,"афдыу").

Проще и короче говоря мне хотелось бы упростить этот код

```
if filter_messages == "False" or filter_messages == "false" or filter_messages == "f" or filter_messages == "FALSE" or filter_messages == "F" or filter_messages == "0":
   #Код
```

Я пробовал

```
if filter_messages == "False" or "false" or "f" or "FALSE" or "F" or "0":

if filter_messages in "False" or "false" or "f" or "FALSE" or "F" or "0":
```

Comment: if filter_message in ['False', 'f'...]

Answer (score 0):

решением моей проблемы стала этот [вопрос](https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread2923039.html) и ответ пользователя @splash58

```
filter_listFalse = {"False" , "false" , "f" , "FALSE" , "F" , "0"}
filter_listTrue = {"True" , "true" , "t" , "TRUE" , "T" , "1"}
if filter_messages in filter_listTrue:
   #Код
if filter_messages in filter_listFalse:
   #Код
```